# How to change wordpress gutenberg editor font to match default theme font?

Tags: themes, fonts

I'm using Iconic One Pro theme with Ubuntu as default font, it appears on the site, blog post, everything.

But the wordpress editor is not using the same font (default Noto Sans) on Chrome and Edge.

On Firefox, the editor is using Ubuntu as default font.

I've tried many methods including importing font on function.php / editor.css, etc.

The iop-block-editor-style.css is already importing Ubuntu font for the editor, but for some reason it doesn't work except on Firefox.

And one more problem is that on Firefox, the font changed back to Times New Roman on "list" block.

Can someone help me out? Big thanks!

Comment: Obvious questions, that it sounds like you've probably already considered: is iop-block-editor-style.css definitely loaded in the other browsers, and can you see why it's not picked up in Chrome and Edge? Are there any errors in your browser developer tools about failing to load and parse the fonts? Are the working and not working browsers using the same file format, probably woff2 ?

Comment: But if that's not it, and you're using default blocks, it might be worth checking the bugs on the Gutenberg project on GitHub and/or raising a new one.

Comment: there are many css loaded including wp-editor-font-css with Noto Sans, but on Firefox the default Ubuntu is used on the editor.